# Android drawable with background and gradient on the left

Tags: android, drawable, gradient, shapes

W would like to have a `drawable` which has background and gradient on the left that is about `10dp` wide.

Image of what I would like to achieve:

[image]

1. Red gradient on the left
2. Background on the rest

How I can achieve that?

I've tried `layer-list` with two shapes but with no luck.

Item background:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/gradient" />
</layer-list>
```

Background drawable:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/black" />
</shape>
```

Shape drawable:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="#FFFF0000" android:endColor="#80FF00FF"
        android:angle="90"/>
       <size android:width="10dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: can you explain more exactly what you need and if you have image of expectation better to uploaded, will give better imagination.

Comment: I've uploaded image which will explain it more clearly (I hope ;) )

Answer (score 8):

Create **sidecolor** (or any name you want) **XML** in drawable folder as bellow:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background" android:bottom="5dp"
        android:top="5dp"  android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp"/>  
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/red" android:bottom="5dp"  android:top="5dp"
        android:left="5dp" android:right="280dp" /> 
  </layer-list>
```

then create background XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />    
   </shape>
```

then red XML as shape:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
         android:shape="rectangle">       
      <solid android:color="#B22222" /> 
  </shape>
```

OUTPUT IMAGE :

[image]

ALSO you can create red XML as gradient :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
            android:shape="rectangle">
      <gradient android:startColor="#B22222" android:centerColor="#FFFFFF" 
           android:endColor="#B22222" android:angle="0" /> 
     </shape>
```

OUTPUT IMAGE :

[image]

**UPDATE:**

ALSO you can do it this way to align it to left also control its size as you need ,

first create one XML and called it side color.xml and refer view to it by :

```
android:background="@drawable/sidecolor"
```

sidecolor.xml :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>    
     <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
             <solid android:color="#FF0000" />        
       </shape>    
  </item>

  <item android:left="10dp">
       <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#000000" />
       </shape>
  </item>
     </layer-list>
```

OUTPUY IMAGE :

[image]

Hope Help You.

Comment: I would like to align to the left - in Your example you've hardcoded it to 280dp

Comment: @pixel up to my knowledge this is the way i do it

Comment: But what if I would like to have this black box semi transparent? I would end up having gradient underneath...

Comment: Exactly - I would like it to be semi-transparent.